# OHCL data with symbols in a data.frame, need to extract # of unique closes by symbol (R)

Tags: r

sample data

```
        date symbol    open    high     low   close  volume
1 2015-08-24   ACAD 33.7600 35.8300 32.2300 33.6000 1474700
2 2015-08-25   ACFN  0.1700  0.2000  0.1700  0.1800  125600
3 2015-08-24   ACFN  0.1700  0.2000  0.1700  0.1700  125600
4 2015-08-24   ACGL 22.6667 22.7233 21.4267 22.3933 2314200
5 2015-08-24    ACH  7.5600  7.9200  7.5400  7.7200  260300
6 2015-08-24   ACHC 69.0900 70.8800 58.7000 69.7100 1823400
7 2015-08-24   ACHN  6.9800  7.2500  6.7100  7.2500 4556400
8 2015-08-25   ACHN  6.9800  7.2500  6.7100  7.2500 4556400
```

What I'm trying to do is

derive the # of unique close values

by symbol

ex.

Unique Close values by symbol

```
ACAD - 1
ACFN - 2
ACGL - 1
ACH  - 1
ACHC - 1
ACHN - 1
```

Comment: Try `table(df1$symbol)` or `df1 %>% count(symbol)`

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for.  I want it to break down the # of unique prices by symbol.  All that does it count the # of unique symbols. I'm afraid I need a loop which would be expensive.

Comment: I think I have to pvt is first

Comment: Ok, got it.  I posted a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct` to count the number of unique elements of 'close' grouped by 'symbol'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(symbol) %>% 
    summarise(n = n_distinct(close))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  symbol     n
#  <chr>  <int>
#1 ACAD       1
#2 ACFN       2
#3 ACGL       1
#4 ACH        1
#5 ACHC       1
#6 ACHN       1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2015-08-24", "2015-08-25", "2015-08-24", 
"2015-08-24", "2015-08-24", "2015-08-24", "2015-08-24", "2015-08-25"
), symbol = c("ACAD", "ACFN", "ACFN", "ACGL", "ACH", "ACHC", 
"ACHN", "ACHN"), open = c(33.76, 0.17, 0.17, 22.6667, 7.56, 69.09, 
6.98, 6.98), high = c(35.83, 0.2, 0.2, 22.7233, 7.92, 70.88, 
7.25, 7.25), low = c(32.23, 0.17, 0.17, 21.4267, 7.54, 58.7, 
6.71, 6.71), close = c(33.6, 0.18, 0.17, 22.3933, 7.72, 69.71, 
7.25, 7.25), volume = c(1474700L, 125600L, 125600L, 2314200L, 
260300L, 1823400L, 4556400L, 4556400L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can apply this to duplicate dates?  I used two of these (one for n_distinct) and one for length(date) and subtracted them.  And it works.  But it would be nice to have it in one line.  If I try to swap date for close it cries about not able to work with true/false. 
#duplicate Dates
num_Unique_Dates <- eod_completewNA %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(date))

num_Dates <- eod_completewNA %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  summarise(n = length(date))

diff_Dates = num_Dates$n-num_Unique_Dates$n

Comment: @thistleknot  Not clear about the question.  can you please post as a new question?

Comment: not really a big deal.  I was able to get it to work with two of your statements modified and then subtract two data.frames from each other.  Would be nice to do it in one.  But I got a 4-6 hour operation I need to figure out on how to reduce

Comment: @thistleknot  May be you need `end_completewNA %>% group_by(symbol) %>% summarise(n1 = n() - n_distinct(date))`